# how to pass attribute useArrows from TreePanel to its Treenodes in extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs3, treenode, treepanel

I am trying to access useArrows property of TreePanel from TreeNode .
Can anyone suggest me how to access TreePanel properties from TreeNode in extjs?

Answer (score 0):

Nohow.
If you are using ExtJS 3, you can use `Ext.ComponentMgr.get()` method.